# Catch child process exception in parent process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am creating multiple processes which are running crawlers separately. I want to ensure that if there is some exception in crawler process, I am able to catch it in Parent Process.
Here is the process creation code:

```
try:
    caching_process = Process(target=run_crawler_process, args=(Config.CRAWLER_NAME, locations,
                                                               city_payloads_map, cycle_count))
    caching_process.start()
except Exception as processException:
    raise processException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with `Process` objects. The [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) or the [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) allow to do that.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
task = pool.apply_async(run_crawler_process, (Config.CRAWLER_NAME, locations,c ity_payloads_map, cycle_count))

try:
    task.get()
except Exception as error:  
    print("Error while processing task: %s" % error)
```