# how to catch multiprocessing exit reasons?

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing

When using python `multiprocessing` package to create a process, after running the process few times. Subprocess will exit with no exceptions thrown, so how to find the reason why this process exit?

```
task = create_process('plugin1', start_process)
task.join()
if task.exception:
    pid, e, tb = task.exception

def create_process(name, func):
    task = Process(target=func, name=name, args=(name,))
    task.daemon = True
    task.start()
    return task

class Process(multiprocessing.Process): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._pconn, self._cconn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self._exception = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            multiprocessing.Process.run(self)
            print(50 * '1', os.getpid(), self.name)
            import setproctitle
            setproctitle.setproctitle("test5")
            print(50 * '0', os.getpid(), self.name)
            self._cconn.send(None)
        except Exception as e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self._cconn.send((os.getpid(), e, tb))

    @property
    def exception(self):
        if self._pconn.poll():
            self._exception = self._pconn.recv()
        return self._exception
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch child process exception in parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614531/catch-child-process-exception-in-parent-process)

Comment: It isn't clear either a) what your code is trying to do nor b) what the expected behaviour is.  You say "Subprocess will exit with no exceptions".  Do you expect the subprocess to run forever?  Do you expect it to exit with some exception?  What is printed by your process?